# How can I use a variable from another function and event?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am making this code for a game where once a player joins the game his vehicles spawn and once he leaves they get destroyed. The vehicles are created at his command and saved on the database. I can create the vehicles, spawn them once he joins, but I can't seem to find a way do destroy them once he leaves, because they're defined on different events.

Function to create the vehicles:

```
function vehicle2Func(player, vehicle) {
    var socialID = player.rgscId;
    vehicleCreate = mp.vehicles.new(mp.joaat(vehicle), player.position, {
        heading: player.heading,
        dimension: player.dimension
    });
    pos = player.position;
    var vehicleModel = vehicleCreate.model
    pool.getConnection((err, con) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            con.query("SELECT playerID FROM players WHERE scID = ?", [socialID], function (err, result) {
                var playerID = result[0].playerID
                con.query("INSERT INTO vehicles (vehicleType, vehicleModel, vehicleOwner, vehicleSpawnX, vehicleSpawnY, vehicleSpawnZ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", ["players", vehicleModel, playerID, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z] , function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else {
                        player.outputChatBox("Veículo adicionado com sucesso.")
                        con.release();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

mp.events.addCommand("v2", (player, vehicle)  => {
    if (!vehicle) player.outputChatBox()
    vehicle2Func(player, vehicle);
})
```

Event and function when the player joins

```
mp.events.add("playerJoin", (player) => {
    var socialID = player.rgscId;
    pool.getConnection((err, con) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        con.query("SELECT playerID FROM players WHERE scID = ?", [socialID], function (err, result) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            playerID = result[0].playerID
            con.query("SELECT vehicleID, vehicleModel, vehicleSpawnX, vehicleSpawnY, vehicleSpawnZ FROM vehicles WHERE vehicleType = ? AND vehicleOwner = ?", ["players", playerID], function (err, result) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    vehicleModel = result[i].vehicleModel
                    result[i].vehicleID = mp.vehicles.new(parseInt(vehicleModel), new mp.Vector3(result[i].vehicleSpawnX, result[i].vehicleSpawnY, result[i].vehicleSpawnZ),
                        {
                            dimension: player.dimension
                        });
                }
            });
        });
        con.release()
    });
});
```

Now, I want them to be destroyed once the player leaves, but for that I need their definition (result[i].vehicleID . I can't delete them from the vehicleID stored on the database. I think. I'm still learning. Maybe I'm doing everything wrong. Thanks for the help.